# Cannot find data from index in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, mnist

I am trying to show image of specific index using matplotlib, but it is showing me error which i did not get why ? I am trying to get index 0 of mnist data and resize it to 28 by 28 pixel and then show that index value by plot.show() function.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

some_digit = X[0]
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)

plt.imshow(
    some_digit_image, 
    cmap = matplotlib.cm.binary,
    interpolation="nearest")

plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Machinelearning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-246778f0802e> in <module>
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 
----> 5 some_digit = X[0]
      6 some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)
      7 

~/Machinelearning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

~/Machinelearning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
import numpy as np

x = [36000]
```

to

```
np.array(x.iloc[36000])
```